# Going from Closed Categories to Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

**EDIT:** I trimmed down the exposition a bit. I really just wanted everyone to know what my approach has been, but what I had was a bit bloated.

Suppose we have a closed category $V$ as defined [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category), and suppose that for each $b \in V$, $[b, -]$ has a left adjoint $-\otimes b$. My conjecture is that $- \otimes -$ makes $V$ into a monoidal category. To this end, I've been able to define all the structural natural isomorphisms for a monoidal category (and show that they really are natural isomorphisms) except $\alpha^{-1} \colon a \otimes (b \otimes c) \rightarrow (a \otimes b) \otimes c$.

My usual approach has been to work with Hom-sets and use adjointness to get to a Hom-set that has a morphism that I've already defined. This approach failed for $\alpha^{-1}$. Instead I was able to show that I'd be able to get to $\alpha^{-1}$ if I had either
$$
\Psi^* \colon [a, [b,c]] \rightarrow [a \otimes b, c]
$$
or
$$
T \colon [a, b] \rightarrow [a \otimes c, b \otimes c]
$$

**Question:** Given a closed catgory $V$ such that $[b, -]$ has a left adjoint $- \otimes b$ for each object $b \in V$, how can we (or can we) define a natural map $\alpha^{-1} \colon a \otimes (b \otimes c) \rightarrow (a \otimes b) \otimes c$?

If not, what is a counterexample to this conjecture? It seems unlikely to me that we would be able to define every structural morphism for a monoidal category except $\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: If anyone has access to Eilenberg and Kelly's _Closed Categories_, I think it might be answered in there.

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121829/tensor-products-from-internal-hom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to G.M. Kelly's *Examples of Non-monadic Structures on Categories* (page 63), downloadable [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404980901164), $\alpha$ is not necessarily an isomorphism if we only have a closed category with an adjoint to $[-,-]$. Unfortunately, as far I can tell, Kelly does not give a counterexample.

Thanks to Buschi Sergio in the comments for [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210795/rectifying-the-definition-of-a-closed-category?noredirect=1#comment539732_210795) question for pointing me to Day and LaPlaza's paper [On Embedding Closed Categories](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ18_03%2FS0004972700008236a.pdf&code=90177cc66dc56ea3ae713db408d36660) which has an example of this behavior. Once I understand this example better, I'll try to explain it here. It uses a certain subcategory of the category of topological spaces to get the desired behavior.

Regardless, if we require the adjoint to be "internal" in the sense that we have a natural isomorphism
$$
\Psi^* \colon [a, [b, c]] \rightarrow [a \otimes b, c]
$$

then everything works out and $\alpha$ *is* an isomophism, and the resulting structure *is* a monoidal category.